# How to change category grid view - Image size

Tags: magento-1.9, category, grid, product-images, ce-1.9.2.2

Is there anyway to change the image size in category grid view?

Can I do this with custom design in the category or does it have to be applied in every category?

I would like my images to be larger ideally around 350px and perhaps add a border around them.

I have browsed through stackexchange and google got some templatemonster results too, tried everything (refreshed cache and added new product after the changes) but I can't seem to make it work...

Any ideas? 
using magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 2):

First, locate the category grid template. If you know for sure, which template is used, you can do that using the template path hints ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint ).

Next, find how the image display is made. Be attentive, as this template type usually has two ways of product output methods: Grid and List. It's possible to make a mistake by editing the List, that, as a rule, goes first in the code.

In the standard theme, right after the check goes:

```
getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

goes the List View block. In 'else' of this check goes the Grid View. This is the place, where the changes should be made. Find somewhat like this:

```
<img src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>"
width="135"
height="135"
class="product-image-first"
alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
/>
```

And change all the values for resize(), width and height with the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

To increase image size in grid view
Copy file `list.phtml` `app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/template/catalog/product/` into your theme 
and inside grid mode code, change below code

```
<?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
```

to

```
<?php $_imgSize = 350; // your required image size ?>
```